# PHP - Unable to update MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create email verification but for some reason, I can't update my **MySQL** table. I've tried various different ways of doing it but I can't seem to get it to update.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "x");

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
    // Verify data
    $email = mysqli_escape_string($_GET['email']); // Set email variable
    $hash = mysqli_escape_string($_GET['hash']); // Set hash variable

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND hash = ?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $hash);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 

    if($count < 1){
    // We have a match, activate the account

        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "UPDATE users SET active ='1' WHERE email=? AND hash=?"); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss",$email, $hash);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 

        echo '<div class="statusmsg">Your account has been activated, you can now login</div>';
    }
    else{
    // No match -> invalid url or account has already been activated.
        echo '<div class="statusmsg">The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.</div>';
    }
}
else{
    // Invalid approach
    echo '<div class="statusmsg">Invalid approach, please use the link that has been send to your email.</div>';
}

?>
    <!-- stop PHP Code -->
```

Comment: Please hide your creds. Also, What is happening when the script is executed? Any errors/warning/notice?

Comment: no errors just doesn't update on myphpadmin

Comment: try changing the variables you used for the update. Different variables for select and update. `$statement `

Comment: tried that didn't fix it

Comment: what does your form look like?

Answer (score 0):

One of the probable reason of rows not getting updated because, you are checking of number of rows less than 1, which would be false, since you are expecting some rows from `SELECT` statement.

```
if($count < 1){
```

instead, it should be

```
if($count == 1){
```

Answer (score 0):

In your IF challenge you are looking if there is NO entry in the db with that hash and rmail. But there should be one that is not yet active. So: There should be exactly 1 entry in the db.

```
if($count == 1){
```

That should do the trick.

You should further also look for

```
AND active=0
```

In your first SQL statement to avoid 2 activations or remove the hash from your db once the uset is activated.

Comment: ah okay I see, so that worked but now there's a new problem, $count doesn't equal 1 even though when I test it on myphpadmin it works